# How to plot data grouped by a factor, but not as a boxplot

Tags: r, plot

In R, given a vector

```
casp6 <- c(0.9478638, 0.7477657, 0.9742675, 0.9008372, 0.4873001, 0.5097587, 0.6476510, 0.4552577, 0.5578296, 0.5728478, 0.1927945, 0.2624068, 0.2732615)
```

and a factor:

```
trans.factor <- factor (rep (c("t0", "t12", "t24", "t72"), c(4,3,3,3)))
```

I want to create a plot where the data points are grouped as defined by the factor. So the categories should be on the x-axis, values in the same category should have the same x coordinate.

Simply doing `plot(trans.factor, casp6)` does almost what I want, it produces a boxplot, but I want to see the individual data points.

Comment: Are you tied to plot ?  I know this is possible using ggplot2.

Comment: Not at all. In which package is ggplot2?

Comment: As Jonathan has answered, ggplot2 will let you do this, plus let you jitter the points so no two points overlap each other if they have the same y value.  Check out Hadley's website http://had.co.nz/ggplot2/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

```
require(ggplot2)
qplot(trans.factor, casp6)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can do it with `ggplot2`, using `facets`. When I read *"I want to create a plot where the data points are grouped as defined by the factor"*, the first thing that came to my mind was `facets`.

But in this particular case, faster alternative should be:

```
plot(as.numeric(trans.factor), casp6)
```

And you can play with plot options afterwards (`type`, `fg`, `bg`...), but I recommend sticking with `ggplot2`, since it has much cleaner code, great functionality, you can avoid overplotting... etc. etc.

Learn how to deal with factors. You got barplot when evaluating `plot(trans.factor, casp6)` 'cause `trans.factor` was class of `factor` (ironically, you even named it in such manor)... and `trans.factor`, as such, was declared **before** a continuous (numeric) variable within `plot()` function... hence `plot()` "feels" the need to subset data and draw boxplot based on each part (if you declare continuous variable first, you'll get an ordinary graph, right?). `ggplot2`, on the other hand, interprets factor in a different way... as *"an ordinary"*, numeric variable (this stands for syntax provided by *Jonathan Chang*, you must specify `geom` when doing something more complex in `ggplot2`).

But, let's presuppose that you have one continuous variable and a factor, and you want to apply histogram on each part of continuous variable, defined by factor levels. This is where the things become complicated with base graph capabilities.

```
# create dummy data
> set.seed(23)
> x <- rnorm(200, 23, 2.3)
> g <- factor(round(runif(200, 1, 4)))
```

By using base graphs (`package:graphics`):

```
par(mfrow = c(1, 4))
tapply(x, g, hist)
```

ggplot2 way:

```
qplot(x, facets = . ~ g)
```

Try to do this with `graphics` in one line of code (semicolons and custom functions are considered cheating!):

```
qplot(x, log(x), facets = . ~ g)
```

Let's hope that I haven't bored you to death, but helped you!

Kind regards,
*aL3xa*

Answer (score 4):

I find the following solution:

```
stripchart(casp6~trans.factor,data.frame(casp6,trans.factor),pch=1,vertical=T)
```

simple and direct.

(Refer eg to http://www.mail-archive.com/r-help@r-project.org/msg34176.html)

Answer (score 3):

You may be able to get close to what you want using lattice graphics by doing:

```
library(lattice)    
xyplot(casp6 ~ trans.factor, 
       scales = list(x = list(at = 1:4, labels = levels(trans.factor))))
```

Answer (score 3):

I think there's a better solution (I wrote it for a workshop a few days ago), but it slipped my mind. Here's an ugly substitute with base graphics. Feel free to annotate the x axis *ad libitum*. Personally, I like Greg's solution.

```
plot(0, 0, xlim = c(1, 4), ylim = range(casp6), type = "n")
points(casp6 ~ trans.factor)
```

Answer (score 3):

**No extra package needed**

I'm a bit late to the party, but I found that you can get the desired result very easily with the standard plot function -- simply convert the factor to a numeric value:

```
plot(as.numeric(trans.factor), casp6)
```

Answer (score 1):

10 year old question...but if you want a neat base R solution:

```
plot(trans.factor, casp6, border=NA, outline=FALSE)
points(trans.factor, casp6)
```

The first line sets up the plot but draws nothing.  The second adds the points.  This is slightly neater than the solutions that force x to be numeric.